# iterate list and compare it's values with dict

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I am dealing with 1. list of dictionaries and 2. list. I am trying to:
1. iterate through list (list1),
2. Match the list1's value with the `ID` of API response, if found- put entire dict in a new_dict
3. else skip

API response in Json format:

```
   list_of_dict=[{"id":1500,
      "f_name": "alex",
       "age": 25
      },

      {"id" :1501,
       "f_name":"Bob",
       "age": 30
      },
      {"id" :1600,
       "f_name":"Charlie",
       "age": 35
      }
      ...
     ]
```

And a list1:

```
list1=[1500,1501,1211.....]
```

According to this, `1500 & 1501` is present in list_of_dict so that entire dict will be added in new_dict.

My attempt:

```
new_dict=dict()
for i,val in enumerate(list1):
    #assuming val found in dict
    #so put it in new dict
    print i ,"=",val
    new_dict.update({"id": val,"name":name, "age":age})
```

What i see is this code taking only last item of the list and updates the dict.. but in my case, new_dict will contains two dictionaries with id `1500` and `1501`. What i am missing?

Comment: Lets say that `list1 = [1500, 1501]` (since those are both in the example `list_of_dict`) -- What would you want `new_dict` to be after processing?

Comment: I think OP wants the ouput to be a list. That update operator overwrites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_of_dict = [{"id":1500,
                     "f_name": "alex",
                     "age": 25
                     },

                     {"id" :1501,
                      "f_name":"Bob",
                      "age": 30
                     },
                     {"id" :1600,
                      "f_name":"Charlie",
                      "age": 35
                     }
                  ]

list1=[1500,1501,1211]

ret = filter(lambda x: x['id'] in list1, list_of_dict)
print ret
```

Check out the useful and simple filter function built-in to python.  It iterates through an iterable (list) and returns only the items that return true for the provided function

In this case, our filtering function is:

```
lambda x: x['id'] in list1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    list_of_dict = [{"id":1500,
                     "f_name": "alex",
                     "age": 25
                     },

                     {"id" :1501,
                      "f_name":"Bob",
                      "age" 30
                     },
                     {"id" :1600,
                      "f_name":"Charlie",
                      "age" 35
                     }
                     ...
                  ]

dicts = {d['id']:d for d in list_of_dict}
list1=[1500,1501,1211.....]

answer = [dicts[k] for k in list1 if k in dicts]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple list comprehension, filtering the dicts by whether their id is in the list:

```
result = [d for d in list_of_dict if d["id"] in list1]
```

If your `list1` is larger, you might want to turn it into a `set` first, so the lookup is faster:

```
list1_as_set = set(list1)
result = [d for d in list_of_dict if d["id"] in list1_as_set]
```